# FK and IK rig for the same mesh

Tags: rigging

Is there a way to have one rig for FK and one rig for IK for the same mesh? Some animation programs allow me to easily change between both. Source Filmmaker for instance has a built in IK solver that just changes everything to FK and vice versa on the spot. Is there such a feature in Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having both FK and IK is essential in every rig for animation, so yes, Blender does offer this.

There are 2 easy options:

1. You can pose an FK armature with [Auto IK](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/posing/editing.html#auto-ik). It has huge limitations:

   > The auto IK option in the Tool Shelf enables a temporary IK constraint when posing bones. The chain acts from the tip of the selected bone to root of the uppermost parent bone. Note that this mode lacks options, and only works by applying the resulting transform to the bones in the chain.
2. [Riggify addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Rigging/Rigify) (it's included with every Blender)

   - You import a metarig (biped), adjust it to the character proportions, then you generate the final rig from it and you skin the character to the rig. It comes with FK-IK controls and buttons in GUI to switch between (via included script run from those buttons).
   - For non-biped characters you will have to build the metarig yourself, then generate the final rig with all the features:

     [How to use the Rigify building blocks for non-human rigs?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44121/how-to-use-the-rigify-building-blocks-for-non-human-rigs)

Setting up such feature rich custom rig yourself requires lots of steps and some knowledge and a bit of coding. It's nowhere near as easy as in Maya (or probably Source Filmmaker also) as there are tools to do the IK/FK switching for you, in Blender it has to be scripted by you.