# Rigging in rigify for custom rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

I got a question. How do I create custom rigs in rigify made from an armature that I didn't rig to a mesh yet but I created the armature? I believe I would be able to do this because I read somewhere that you can add samples or even generate a rigify rig from a rig you built yourself from bones. But I have been unable to find a good tutorial on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated thanks. 
The reason I am asking this is because I get the impression that rigify allows you to make non humanoid rigs and rigs with unusual anatomy.

Comment: Is it answered here: [How to use the rigify building blocks for non human rigs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44121/how-to-use-the-rigify-building-blocks-for-non-human-rigs)?

Comment: That answer was kind of dated if it was the one I think it was.

Comment: It isn't answered clearly on that particular answer, for one the answer is really dated.... Like from four maybe five years ago, not current or particularly up to date. Second, the answer doesn't really tell you how to make your own custom rigify samples clearly, nor does it say anything about how to use a regular rig you built yourself to generate a rigify rig. My question remains mostly unanswered at this time. If anyone has a better answer please let me know.

Comment: The rigify addon functions still the same, even after 3 years. But I updated the info that animal parts are now available and included a link to the manual to an archive, because it is probably being moved atm and not available elsewhere. Hope it helps you now better.

Comment: Pls could you provide a link to this? I can't find it when I am trying to find what you updated ...

Comment: There is a link in my first comment to that answer, is it not clickable? Weird, maybe a browser issue.. this is the full address: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44121/how-to-use-the-rigify-building-blocks-for-non-human-rigs

Comment: I read the manual, but it really doesn't explain anything like making a armature rig you built from a single bone and then generating a rigify rig from that armature rig. I can't find anything that is really understandable that tells me how to do it.

Comment: I'm guessing that isn't within the scope of it's functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely customize your Rigify Meta Rig which would allow you to rig (almost) any character. The "secret" is in understand the Building Blocks or "rig types" that Rigify provides.

I made a tutorial series on exactly that. Here is the series page

https://cgdive.com/rigify

Or the youtube playlist

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJv68SSdwxip33M7snakl6Dx

I hope this is a reasonable "self-promotion". There is very little info on this topic. I learned the basics from this video by Ivan Cappiello (one of past maintainers of Rigify)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txJ-2zUQSTg

And of course, there is the Rigify manual which can be very useful. However it is has been lagging behind the actual development of the addon.
The 2.8 manual actually does not include images as of this writing.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/rigging/rigify/index.html?highlight=rigify

So it may be better to look at the old version of the manual
https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Rigging/Rigify/#Advanced_Usage